70s–80s sci-fi space movie; human character is floating through a black hole; an alien face appears, spits in his face and tells some sort of bad joke
I'm looking for a 1970s or 1980s sci-fi space movie. If memory serves me correctly, this was a comedy/scifi of sorts. I saw it on HBO once, back in the early 1980s.
The scene I remember is that the human character is floating through a black hole or something like that. He was floating through space and time, so to speak, without a ship. He is wearing a possibly dark blue or black jumpsuit with a zipper up the front and no helmet. It looked as if he were floating towards the camera. 
An alien face appears and spits in his face and says in a raspy voice, “Ha ha ha, I always liked that one.” The face tells some sort of bad joke. Then it just kind of disappears. The alien face was a large, translucent circle. Possibly with a cigar. It is not humanoid. Its voice was sort of like Pizza the Hutt from Spaceballs but without the accent. It was on the character’s right and the audience's left. It may have looked like a comical depiction of the Earth's moon, but it was translucent like a ghost.
Black is the only color in the background I can remember. It faded slowly into the emptiness of the time warp / black hole.
It wasn’t The Ice Pirates. I just finished watching that movie.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What kind of clothes is the human wearing?  A spacesuit, a jumpsuit, what?

A jumpsuit and no helmet

The alien face was a large translucent circle.  Possibly with a cigar.  The voice was sort of like pizza the hut from spaceballs but without the accent.

Do you remember any colors of that scene? Background, lights? Was alien face humanoid or no?

Not humanoid. Black is the only color in the back round I can remember.  Btw everyone, thank you. This has been bugging me for 22 years. I saw the movie on HBO once back in the early 1980s.

Anything of the plot? Were there any spaceships, planets, other aliens? Were they fighting for something?

I can’t remember the plot.  There was fighting.  It was as if he was lost in a time warp or something similiar.  It wasn’t Ice Pirates.  I literally just finished watching that movie.
The character as I remember was floating through space and times, so to speak, without a ship.

@Tom If you remember any additional details, please [edit] your question and add them.

@Tom so you just seen man floating in some space, alien head saying some bad joke and it was the end? Was man just floating in place or floating away into some nothingness?

Can you also describe that jumpsuit? Color, some zippers?

Only a comment, because it doesn't really match (but memories are funny like that). It's possible that you are remembering a scene from "The adventures of Baron Munchhausen", where the Baron encounters the king and queen of the moon. They can remove their heads, and often float about with just the head and the neck-ruffle collar. In one part, one of the bodies (separate from the head) is being tickled, and the head is laughing. The heads are not translucent, and I don't recall a cigar, though.
